# implementing the IComparable Interface on two string fields

Tags: c#, compare

How do I implement the IComparable Interface on two string fields?

Using the Person class example below. If Person objects are added to a list. How do I sort the list based on Surname first THEN Forename?

```
Class Person
{
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Forname { get; set; }
}
```

Something like? :

```
myPersonList.Sort(delegate(Person p1, Person p2)
{
    return p1.Surname.CompareTo(p2. Surname);
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Or you could sort a list like this:

```
myPersonList.Sort(delegate(Person p1, Person p2)
{
    int result = p1.Surname.CompareTo(p2.Surname);
    if (result == 0)
        result = p1.Forname.CompareTo(p2.Forname);
    return result;
});
```

Alternatively you could have `Person` implement `IComparable<Person>` with this method:

```
public int CompareTo(Person other)
{
    int result = this.Surname.CompareTo(other.Surname);
    if (result == 0)
        result = this.Forname.CompareTo(other.Forname);
    return result;
}
```

**EDIT** As Mark commented, you might decide you need to check for nulls.  If so, you should decide whether nulls should be sorted to the top or bottom.  Something like this:

```
if (p1==null && p2==null)
    return 0; // same
if (p1==null ^ p2==null)
    return p1==null ? 1 : -1; // reverse this to control ordering of nulls
```

Comment: What about checking for nulls in .Surname?

Comment: @Tymec, just repeat the same pattern as used for p1 and p2, but with p1.Surname and p2.Surname.

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
int surnameComparison = p1.Surname.CompareTo(p2.Surname);

if (surnameComparison <> 0)
  return surnameComparison;
else
  return p1.Forename.CompareTo(p2.Forename);
```